# Windows container capture tcpdump

Tags: dockerfile, windows-container

How to capture network traffic packets inside windows container?

We have OpenShift Windows Container and not sure how to capture the network traffic like using WireShark inside the container

Please provide any example on how to do this.

From our container a TCP connection is made and after idle time of 10 mins this is timing out.

Are there any tools in the container that I could install?

Or from the worker node what is the command that can I use to get the tcpdump

I dont have any knowledge on how to debug this

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [WinDump](https://www.winpcap.org/windump/).

You can use it in the terminal;

```
windump -i <interface> -w <output_file.pcap>
```

Replace `<interface>` with the name of the network interface you want to capture traffic from (e.g., `eth0`, `Ethernet`, etc.), and <output_file.pcap> with the desired name for the output file.